# Selecting Date from database column filtered by month and year

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I have a database column, sales_date which stores the date a particular sales took place. The data is stored using PHP date(). how do i select data from rows using date and time as filters?

i have tried using the WHERE clause in my SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT sales_date, sales_amount from sales_table 
WHERE YEAR(sales_day) = $yr AND MONTH(sales_day) = $mn
```

```
$getComm = $this->db->prepare('SELECT sales_date, sales_total, sales_comm from bakery_sales WHERE u_id = :u_id AND YEAR(sales_date) = :sales_year AND MONTH(sales_date) = :sales_month');
  $getComm->bindParam(':u_id', $_SESSION['userid'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $getComm->bindParam(':sales_year', $yr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $getComm->bindParam(':sales_month', $mn,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I expect the query to return rows with the selected month and year.

Comment: Does it work or not?

Comment: How is the column defined in your database? Please provide an example of the date values that are stored in the database.

Comment: @forpas, it does not work.@Dave it is dateTime and an example is 2019-03-25.

Comment: So if you try something like: `SELECT sales_date, sales_amount from sales_table 
WHERE YEAR(sales_day) = 2019 AND MONTH(sales_day) = 3` what do you get?

Comment: @forpas, it works that way. Problem is I am expecting month and year from user input. And the user selected month will be "March" and not "3"

Comment: Then do this: `SELECT sales_date, sales_amount from sales_table 
WHERE YEAR(sales_day) = $yr AND MONTHNAME(sales_day) = $mn`